# Toggling wrap and column flow with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a responsive design in which items in a wide screen should wrap like this:

```
+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |
|  A   |  B   |  C   |
|      |      |      |
+--------------------+
|      |      |
|  D   |  E   |
|      |      |
+------+------+
```

And in a narrow screen should stack up vertically like this:

```
+------+
|      |
|  A   |
|      |
+------+
|      |
|  B   |
|      |
+------+
|      |
|  C   |
|      |
+------+
|      |
|  D   |
|      |
+------+
|      |
|  E   |
|      |
+------+
```

Right now I'm doing like this for these solutions respectively:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
----
flex-direction: column;
```

But is there a single decleration with which I accomplish the above by simply toggling the value?

Comment: toggle wich value ? .. you can keep the wrap and add column

Comment: Added a sample to my answer as well

Comment: Elegant! I wish I could give you more points :)

Comment: Great, thanks...and 1 is good enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shorthand `flex-flow: <flex-direction> || <flex-wrap>`

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-flow-property

---

The default value is `row nowrap`, and if one only set one of them, the other will be its default, e.g.:

- `flex-flow: column`  - column direction, no wrap
- `flex-flow: wrap`  - row direction, wrap

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/awbvoe1q/)

Stack snippet

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}

#container > div {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightblue;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  #container {
    flex-flow: column;
  } 
}

#container > div:last-child { background: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <p>DIV 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>DIV 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but he can keep the flex-wrap ... and toogle only the row/column of flex direction, no ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Of course, though I were of the impression OP wanted to toggle both values in one go, not just one, as if only one, why ask in the first place.

Comment: maybe ... i didn't understand very well what he meant, by the way congrats for the flexbox gold ;) am surprised only 3 people have it !! i hope i will be the fourth one but still too far :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif It took me about 750 answers to get the Gold, so you have a few left from yours 64 :) ... and here I got one more ;)

Comment: yes but with you and Michael_b there is no way to put something with flexbox :/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hahaha...fair enough, but I have a lot of work coming up and will slow down a little, so you will get more questions to answer from now on :)

Comment: no keep it going, it's more funny when it's challenging ;)